# Автопозиционирование яндекс карты по точкам

Tags: яндекс-карты

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы яндекс карта масштабировалась и выставляла центр относительно меток на карте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать коллекцию

```
myCol = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
```

Добавить точки в коллекцию

```
placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([50,40]);
myCol.add(placemark);
```

Добавить точки на карту

```
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCol);
```

Сказать карте, что нужно сделать автопозиционирование на основе точек

```
myMap.setBounds(myCol.getBounds());
```

Иногда может понадобиться вот такой вот хак

```
myMap.setZoom(myMap.getZoom());
```

Comment: Не могу понять почему в таком случае: http://pastebin.com/baFhD60K не отрабатывает setBounds... Метки на карте отрисовывает, а позиционировать отказывается... Помогите пожалуйста советом.

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, рабочий пример на http://jsfiddle.net, например

Comment: Здесь http://jsfiddle.net/p816jn9d/2/ уже исправленный рабочий вариант. Проблема была в том, что я не учёл асинхронность работы геокодирования, решение нашёл совместно с коллегами такое. Если я правильно всё сам понимаю, то здесь setBounds применяется после геокодирования каждой точки.

Comment: в вашем примере `setBounds` применяется когда обработался последний `geocode`. то есть вроде как все верно. проставьте точек 10. поставьте `alert(1)` в `if` с проверкой на порядковое число.