# Яндекс карты, масштаб

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Доброго времени. Суть проблемы в следующем. У меня есть карта, на которой находятся метки. Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб при загрузке страницы метки на карте были расположены по масштабу. То есть, нужно установить такой масштаб, чтоб метки влезли, не вылезали за пределы карты и в то же время не сбивались в кучку из за маленького масштаба. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пока вот так. Но как видите, надо увеличить карту, чтоб разглядеть, где и что там конкретно находится. Хотелось бы автоматизировать это.

Comment: Решение нашлось вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426109/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так: `myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds())` или если нужно призумливаться не ко всем меткам на карте то так https://jsfiddle.net/fw11a1sm/

Comment: Спасибо большое. Так и решил проблему) Благодарю за помощь))

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Я не использовал maps-api, и толком не знаю как все работает. Но думаю если перебором из всех меток найти те у которых расстояние между собой больше всех и установить результат + еще несколько метров(или км) как масштаб, то получится то что вам и нужно.

Comment: Интересная идея. Если не найдется стандартного решения для такой, казалось бы, типичной задачи, тогда попытаюсь его использовать. Спасибо!