# Переключение вкладок (табов) с подсветкой города

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

При клике на пункт меняется цвет пункта на красный и идет переключение правого блока на другой. При этом подсвечивается красным цветом название города.

Вот мой код:

```js
< script src = "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false"
type = "text/javascript" > < /script>

  <
  script >

  $('[id^="cont-"').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('[id$="-cont"]').removeClass("activecont");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var temp_arr = id.split('-');

    var to_find = temp_arr['1'];
    $('#' + to_find + '-cont').addClass('activecont');
  });

$(function() {

  $('#nav-cont').on('click', 'li', function(event) {

    $(this).addClass("activecont").siblings().removeClass("activecont");
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#menu-one-mobile").addClass("activecont");

  });

});

<
/script>
```

```css
.cont-inform-block .cont-block__item {
  font-family: "Raleway" sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 53px;
  letter-spacing: 0.26em;
}

.cont-inform-block .cont-block-left {
  width: 32%;
  height: 554px;
  background: #fff;
}

.cont-inform-block .cont-block-list span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cont-inform-block .cont-block-list {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 35%;
  margin-right: 35px;
  float: right;
}

.cont-inform-block .cot-block-menu {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.cont-inform-block .cot-block-menu li {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.cont-inform-block .cont-link {
  color: #000;
}

.cont-main-block {
  display: flex;
}

.cont-contant p {
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 23px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.cont-contant {
  height: 554px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 21%;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.cont-contant__item {
  padding-top: 43px;
  padding-left: 59px;
  padding-right: 52px;
}

.cont-contant img {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 59px;
}

.cont-footer-block {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.activecont a {
  color: #B00000 !important;
}

.activecont {
  color: #B00000 !important;
  display: block !important;
}

.cont-contant {
  display: none;
}

#map {
  width: 46.7%;
  height: 550px
}

#menu-two-mobile {}

@media screen and (max-width: 1566px) {
  #map {
    width: 60%
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-contant {
    width: 29%;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-block-left {
    width: 21%;
  }
  .cont-contant img {
    padding-right: 59px;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-block-list {
    width: 99%;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .cont-inform-block .cont-block-list {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  #map {
    width: 50%
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .cont-inform-block .cont-block-list {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
  #map {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-block-left {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-inform-block .cont-block-list {
    padding-top: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-contant {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-block-left {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cont-inform-block .cont-main-block {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont-inform-block">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container container-md">
      <div class="cont-block-title">
        <h1 class="cont-block__item">Контактная информация</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cont-main-block">
      <div class="cont-block-left">
        <ul class="cont-block-list">
          <li><span><a id="menu-one-mobile" class="cont-link activecont" href="#">Владивосток (3)</a></span>
            <ul id="nav-cont" class="cot-block-menu">
              <li><a id="cont-one" class="cont-link" href="#">Океанский проспект, 87
      Центральный филиал</a></li>
              <li><a id="cont-two" class="cont-link" href="#">Проспект столетия, 51
     Магазин красоты</a></li>
              <li><a id="cont-three" class="cont-link" href="#">Калинина, 8
     Магазин красоты Exclusive</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span><a class="cont-link" href="#">Уссурийск (1)</a></span>
            <ul class="cot-block-menu">
              <li><a id="cont-four" class="cont-link" href="#">Некрасова,39<br>
Филиал Уссурийск</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="one-cont" class="cont-contant activecont">
        <div class="cont-contant__item">
          <p>Главный офис компании Cosmetik Line расположен по адресу:</p>
          <p>г. Владивосток, Океанский пр-т, 87</p>
          <p>Телефон: 8 (800)550-20-29</p>
          <p>E-mail: shop@cosmetikline.ru</p>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
      </div>

      <div id="two-cont" class="cont-contant">
        <div class="cont-contant__item">
          <p> Cosmetik Line расположен по адресу:</p>
          <p>г. Владивосток, Океанский пр-т, 87</p>
          <p>Телефон: 1 (800)550-20-29</p>
          <p>E-mail: shop@cosmetikline.ru</p>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
      </div>

      <div id="three-cont" class="cont-contant">
        <div class="cont-contant__item">
          <p>ТЕСТ ТЕСТ по адресу:</p>
          <p>г. Владивосток, Океанский пр-т, 87</p>
          <p>Телефон: 2 (800)550-20-29</p>
          <p>E-mail: shop@cosmetikline.ru</p>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
      </div>

      <div id="four-cont" class="cont-contant">
        <div class="cont-contant__item">
          <p>Главный офис компании Cosmetik Line расположен по адресу:</p>
          <p>г. Владивосток, Океанский пр-т, 87</p>
          <p>Телефон: 6 (800)550-20-29</p>
          <p>E-mail: shop@cosmetikline.ru</p>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
        <img src="/images/imagecon.jpg">
      </div>


      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container container-md">
      <div class="cont-footer-block">
        <p>Нам важно Ваше мнение по любым вопросам, связанным с организацией деятельности магазина и представленных на его витринах товарах. Мы будем искренне признательны Вам за все высказанные предложения по увеличению ассортимента продукции и улучшению
          обслуживания в наших магазинах и салоне красоты.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @РустамГимранов Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @РустамГимранов Добавил JS да у меня гавно код получился, Вот при клике на Уссурийск нужно еще добавить , а как грамотно сделать ?

Comment: @РустамГимранов может сможете подправить , сейчас получается нужно просто добавить событие при клике на Уссурийск что бы он загорался красным и пункт тоже а в списке Владивосток убирались классы (что бы шрифт не был красным цветом)

Comment: @РустамГимранов а можете с картой яндекса помочь что бы при клике на пункт был переход к маркеру на карте

Comment: [Ищите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81), [пробуйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426109). Не получится, задавайте вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам бы в разметке разобраться, привести её к однообразию для начала. Тогда можно будет избавиться от постоянного прописывания `id` элементам. Посмотрите общий курс по [табам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982073/256824).

```
// Перебор по классам. Т.е. `id` не нужно приписывать.
$(function() {
  // Перебираем все ссылки, которые
  // находятся непосредственно в теге `li`.
  $('li > a.cont-link').each(function(index, element) {
    // Вешаем к каждому найденному элементу
    // функцию обрабочик по клику.
    $(element).on('click', function(event) {
      // Отменяем действие по умолчанию.
      // Чтобы не добавлялся хеш в адресной строке,
      // и не было прокрутки страницы.
      event.preventDefault();

      // Удаляем у всех!!! ссылок и контейнеров
      // с содержимым класс `activecont`.
      $('a.cont-link').removeClass('activecont');
      $('.cont-contant').removeClass('activecont');

      // Добавляем к текущей ссылке, по которой
      // произошел клик и к контейнеру с индексом
      // текущей ссылки класс `activecont`.
      $(this).addClass('activecont');
      $('.cont-contant').eq(index).addClass('activecont');

      // Хитрый поиск родителя, с названием города.
      $(this).parents('li').find('span > .cont-link').addClass('activecont');
    });
  });
});
```